# LDAP Query URL - how to refer an attribute?

Tags: java, url, ldap

I have set up some database connection parameters on an OpenDS ldap server, using my own schema. It looks as the attached screenshot.
[image]

when I try to query the LDAP using following URL, it fails.

`ldap://localhost/db-configname=local1,ou=eways,dc=repository,dc=com?db-serverName?sub`

I have LDAPAdmin that automatically opens LDAP URLs and it says such an object was not found. Can someone please let me know what exactly is the LDAP URL to refer to one of the attributes such as `db-password` or `db-serverName` shown below?

Comment: +1 for a screen shot of my favorite underrated LDAP browser!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens becuase you should specify base dn and use filter option in LDAP URL syntax. Try this:
ldap://localhost/dc=repository,dc=com?db-serverName?sub?(db-configname=local1)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still get the error :               "LDAP Error! No such object 'ldap://localhost/dc=repository,dc=com?db-serverName?sub?(db-configname=local1)' specified as the search base does not exist in the directory server."

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think we have a problem with LDAP Admin utility that you're using to open links. Apparently it only supports self-defined format for LDAP URLs.
http://ldapadmin.sourceforge.net/docs/commandline.html

Comment: Right you are,..! i removed "ldapAdmin", tested the URL with  Java code - accepted your first answer.